# How do you add a nested attribute to permitted parameters for Devise in order for nested form to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, nested-forms, railsapps

I'm running:

- rails 4.1.4
- devise 3.3

I used the RailsApp starter app to set up devise and pundit.  Right now I am having trouble making a nested form attribute save.  I am getting an error:

```
Unpermitted parameters: players
```

I edited the initializer file to show:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :players, :player_attributes => [:position]) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :role, :players, :player_attributes => [:position]) }
end
```

My models are:

```
class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :player

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :player
end
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
class Players < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Players Controller

```
def update
  @player = Player.find[params[:id])
  if @player.update_attributes(secure_params)
     redirect_to players_path, :notice => "Player updated"
  else
     redirect_to players_path, :alert => "Unable to update"
  end
end

private

def secure_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:user_id, :players)
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get nested attributes working by following this guide..

http://kakimotonline.com/2014/03/30/extending-devise-registrations-controller/